# Why am I getting the "Valid table name is required for in, out or format" error with BCP?

Tags: import, cmd, identity, sql-server-2014, bcp

I want to import a table while keeping the identity column.

In cmd, I enter:

```
bcp database.edg.Hello in C:\Users\Tech\Downloads\p.csv -c -E 
       -S 349024ijfpok.windows.net\MSSQLSERVER -T
```

Which returns:

> A valid table name is required for in, out or format options

Is this an issue with the syntax?

Comment: `database.edg.Hello` - is that a valid database name, schema name, and table name?  If you connect to your server, does `select * from database.edg.Hello` succeed?

Comment: It doesn't. edg.Hello works, but when I add my database name in front of it it just gives a syntax error

There is a dash in the real database name, like da-ta-base. It says "incorrect syntax near '-'.

Comment: bracket it.  `[database-name].[edg].[Hello]`

Answer (score 7):

You need brackets for database information. I usually use colon `"` for path as well just to be sure. Complete command:

```
bcp [database].[edg].[Hello] in "C:\Users\Tech\Downloads\p.csv" -c -E 
       -S 349024ijfpok.windows.net\MSSQLSERVER -T
```

Comment: Is this correct? I've used database details without the square brackets, except where there were problem characters, e.g. a database named "ddb-low" caused the error when I used ddb-low.dbo.Person but it went away when I changed to [ddb-low].dbo.Person

Comment: @SteveC Yes you need them for bcp commands, at least I got errors without them.

Comment: Puzzled ... I can happily do exports with name like SpikeDb.dbo.Person but I get the error if I try ddb-low.dbo.Person and the error goes away when I use [ddb-low].dbo.Person